# Paper size options restricted to photo paper

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, printer, setup

I'm running MS Office 2010, with Windows7 Home Premium on an HP dv6. I use an HP Photosmart A310

After re-booting the printer, the only paper size options, in both word & Excel, are the photo paper sizes.

I have tried all the "page layout" & "paper" size options, but cannot find how to add other paper sizes, specifically A4.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your default printer to something else. Word and Excel are pulling the options from the printer driver. There is most likely a "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" printer in your list... try setting that as the default and try again.